# What is the difference in Rails commands: --no-test-framework, --skip-test-unit, and -T?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, command-line

I was under the impression that all three of these were the same, but now that I look into it, it seems they are all different.

I cannot find any good documentation on this by searching.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/Base.html)
and [This Discussion Thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/rubyonrails-talk/122c557gv3/rails-new-project-with-no-test-framework-but-when-creating-a-model-it-invoked-test-unit)

both `-T` and the `--skip-test-unit` options are to be used when initially creating the project (rails new), whereas the `--no-test-framework` is available to later generator commands(rails generate).