# When creating a new rails app, is there any difference between "-T" and "--skip-test-unit"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I did a search on this and came across [this previous question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105723/what-is-the-difference-in-rails-commands-no-test-framework-skip-test-unit). That question answered what makes `--no-test-framework` different from `-T` and `--skip-test-unit`, but it didn't clarify if there was any distinction between the latter two.

So, is there any distinction between `-T` and `--skip-test-unit`, or are they effectively the same?

(For what it's worth, I'm using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"-T" is short version of "--skip-test-unit" they do the same thing. You can see all possible  options and their meaning by running `rails new --help`